# transient-mark-mode permanently on

Tags: emacs, carbon-emacs

Every time I turn off emacs transient-mark-mode is turned off too how can I have it turned on all the time?My emacs is 22.31 carbon version

Comment: Don't forget to add EmacsWiki to your bookmarks: http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/TransientMarkMode

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put it into your startup file (`.emacs`):

```
(transient-mark-mode 1)
```